# Table border affecting cell size

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Can anyone tell me why when I place `border=1` on a table is fixes its layout?

This is the problem: I wrote some JavaScript that makes me an org chart. If I place a border around the tables that make the chart, everything lines up perfectly. If I remove the borders, some of the lines vary wildly (and seemingly randomly) in width. You will notice this in the red lines that connect the org chart.

This is for the inline attribute of "border" (such as `<table border="1">`).

Here are two demos:

Borders (good, looks all lined up): http://andrewvantran.com/table1.html

No borders (bad, all misaligned): http://andrewvantran.com/table2.html

I would like the have the table laid out the way it does with borders, but I don't want the borders! I can't simulate the layout of the table with borders unless I keep the borders (which I don't want). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the table to `border-collapse:collapse;`? By nature the default collapse is `separate` where cells have their own borders. If you set it to collapse they merge and it "looks right"

Comment: The issue is that when I REMOVE the border, the table does not look right. Changing the `border-collapse` did not affect the table without a border.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `border-collapse: collapse;` to your stylesheet. This seems to fix a lot in your case.

Other than that, I'd suggest you at least use widths for the cells. Different browsers handle cell drawing differently. If you specify a width, you can be more sure the cells align right. When testing your graph, use a inspector tool like Firebug to determine where each cell is located. This will help you a lot.

Comment: separate is the default style, no? oh, you edited after I commented.

Comment: right, I was testing with both and got mixed up when typing my answer, thanks.